# Track a moving desktop window WinApi

Tags: windows, winapi

I am trying to track a moving desktop application window so I can move a corresponding transparent overlay window in parity.  Currently, I hook the `EVENT_SYSTEM_MOVESIZEEND` event with `SetWinEventHook`.  Inside my callback, I update the location of my overlay with the new location of the target application window.

This works, but it means that my overlay jumps around after the user lets go of the target window's title bar. I would like my overlay to track the target window **as** it is moving, not just after it **has** been moved.

The only way I can think to do this is to also hook the `EVENT_SYSTEM_MOVESIZESTART` event. When the `START` event fires, spawn a new thread that polls the target windows location and updates my overlay location. Then, when the `END` event fires, kill the polling thread.

Is this a reasonable approach, or is there a better way to achieve the functionality I want.

Thanks.

Comment: Use EVENT_OBJECT_LOCATIONCHANGE or hide the overlay while it is moving.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, it seems like this is what I was looking for. I don't know how I missed it, I'll give it a try.

Comment: Another option is to subclass the target window and handle the `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING` message.

Comment: @RemyLebeau this is not an options since I am tracking another 3rd party application (e.g. Chrome).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per *Hans Passant*'s suggestion on my question. I was indeed looking to hook `EVENT_OBJECT_LOCATIONCHANGE` instead of `EVENT_SYSTEM_MOVESIZEEND`. Once I hooked `LOCATIONCHANGE`, the tracking worked as expected.

One thing of note, by hooking `LOCATIONCHANGE` you will also receive mouse events for the window. You can easily filter the movement of the window by checking the `hwnd` of the `WinEventProc` callback function.

**MSDN:**

`Handle to the window that generates the event, or NULL if no window is associated with the event. For example, the mouse pointer is not associated with a window.`

Comment: Thanks for that MSDN note.

Comment: Probably not relevant to the specific case of this thread, but relevant in the general case:
if "show window contents while dragging" is disabled, the EVENT_OBJECT_LOCATIONCHANGE notification is not received until the mouse is released. 

This makes sense, as the window has not moved yet, and in the case of an overlay works, but in the general case another way of tracking intermediate movements must be found.